# Fire route/controller hooks every time url changes in ember app

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have two routes in this app that are backed by models that have access control logic on the rails side. So when they first load into the application, they've got an `isUnlocked` property that I check after the model loads. If the property is not unlocked, the route should redirect.

So if my router is something like:

```
this.route('thing', { path: 'thing/:thing_id' }, function() {
  this.route('resource', { path: 'resource/:resource_id' });
});
```

And my "resource" route extends something like this:

```
import AuthenticatedRoute from 'doki/routes/authenticated';

export default AuthenticatedRoute.extend({

  requireDean: false,

  activate() {
    this._super();
    this.checkAccess();
  },

  afterModel() {
    this._super();
    this.checkAccess();
  },

  resetController() {
    this._super();
    this.checkAccess();
  },

  checkAccess() {
    // here is where I'll check the model's isUnlocked property and 
    // redirect if it's false or not set
    console.log('checkAccess');
  }

});
```

When I enter /thing/1/resource/1, the model for resource=1 is loaded by the ThingResourceRoute, but if resource=2 is already loaded in the store, if I click over to /thing/1/resource/2, `activate` doesn't fire, `setupController` doesn't fire, etc, so I'm not sure where to do the checkAccess() test.

What's the best place to check the isUnlocked property whenever the URL changes, because "activate", "resetController", et al, don't fire when the URL changes to the same route but a different item that has a different isUnlocked property.

Is there a hook that I can implement that will always be called? Putting an access check in `renderTemplate` seems like it'd work, but that doesn't seem like the right place.

Should I just invalidate the model after updating the model via an API call? If I set isUnlocked to true locally (and don't persist the model via the API), where would I add the check for that in the route/controller chain that it would always check every time it tries to "access" that model?

Comment: Does `this.store.fetchById('resource', params.id)` make the hooks fire? It will reload the resource from the server in any case so it might fire those hooks.

Comment: You need to pass along arguments to calls to `_super`. You can do `this._super.apply(this, arguments)`, or `this._super(...arguments)`. For instance, your call to `super` from `setupController` will not do the right thing because the super method is not getting the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `didTransition` event fires every time the URL is entered—even when the model is already loaded, controller has been setup, and the hooks have all fired—so I'm going to check the model in `didTransition`:

```
actions: {
    didTransition: function() {
      console.log('-- transitioned into', this.routeName, this.get('controller.model'));
    }
}
```